# What does go list ./... do?

Tags: go

I am having trouble understanding what the following command does.

```
go list ./...
```

When I look at the official documentation https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-List_packages, it is not clear to me what the `./...` argument is telling the command.

Comment: It is a duplicate. The question is not quite right but the answer there is spot on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`go list` requires an import path for a package and can give you some listing info for the packages matched this way (you may be interested in its `-f` flag).

`./...` is a wildcard that matches the current folder and all of its subfolders (execute `go help packages` to read more about this somewhat hidden feature), and that can be used with all the built-in Go commands.

So `go list ./...` can list all the Go packages in the current folder and its sub-folders - you may want to call it from `GOPATH` for example.

Comment: When using Go modules, `go list ./...` will also download all dependencies (except for dependencies used by tests I think). This can be a handy way to install production dependencies in a Dockerfile for example. Although if you're going to run `go install` or `go run` right afterwards, then you don't need `go list` since `install` or `run` will install dependencies automatically.

Comment: Addendum: dependencies are automatically downloaded when running `go build` too. So I guess the use case for explicitly downloading dependencies is pretty limited.

Answer (score 1):

```
go list ./...
```

Here `./` tells to start from the current folder, `...` tells to go down recursively.

```
go list ...
```

In any folder lists all the packages, including packages of the standard library first followed by external libraries in your go workspace.